# Node.js: Have node methods changed?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Something is not working very well with my code. I've just started with the first lines of code and installing the packages. Here is the code:

server.coffee

```
require 'coffee-script'
express = require 'express'

app = express()

app.get '/', (req, res) ->
  res.send "Hello from express"

app.listen(3000)
console.log "Server is listening"
```

index.eco

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="end">
<head>
    <title>Our Page</title>
    <body>
        <h1>Our Index</h1>
    </body>
</head>
</html>
```

First I have to say that the `express.createServer()` have change into `express()` but still, when I try to do change in the code

```
res.send "Hello from express"
```

to

```
res.render 'index.eco', layout: false
```

It doesn't work after I run the server. Any ideas?

package.json

```
{
  "name": "coderacer",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "Example",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Ro",
  "license": "BSD-2-Clause",
  "dependencies": {
    "coffee-script": "*",
    "express": "*",
    "eco": "*"
  }
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: TypeError: Property 'engine' of object #<View> is not a function
  at View.render (/home/sasuke/Documents/harddisk/workspace/coderacer/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:76:8)
ETC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't telling Express to use a template engine. In order to use a template engine such as Eco, you will also need Consolidate.js installed. Consolidate.js is a library adapter to allow other templating engines other than EJS and Jade to work with Express.

This is how you the libraries are used:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var cons = require('consolidate');

app.engine('eco', cons.eco);
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render(__dirname + '/template.eco', {
    layout: false
  });
});
```

The Consolidate.js will automatically handle using `require()` on Eco, so that is the only library you need to initialize to use Eco. If you need a CoffeeScript version:

```
express = require("express")
app = express()
cons = require("consolidate")

app.engine "eco", cons.eco
app.get "/", (req, res) ->
  res.render __dirname + "/template.eco", layout: false
```

Comment: I've wrote it in pure Javascript and it worked, but I think the method for this is different, could you explain me a little why using res.type() + res.sendfile() instead of res.render()?

Comment: The `res.render()` function is either for rending a view, or rendering a template *if* you have specified a template engine such as Jade or EJS. If you have no templating engine and just want to server HTML, then just serve the file with `content-type` set to `html`.

Comment: Thanks. But also I had installed the eco dependency with the npm package manager. So it should work out using `res.render()`

Comment: Then please show more of your code, what you have provided isn't sufficient.

Comment: I've included the package.json file now

Comment: Updated answer. The reason is still the same as before.

Comment: But I do have a template engine to work, that's my problem, that is not displaying when I do the call.

Comment: What is not displaying? If you have shown all your code, then the problem is that you are *not telling Express to actually use Eco*.

Comment: I've installed coffeescript and node in my computer. Then I've started the npm and adding the coffeescript, express and eco dependencies. Then I've coded what I've shown and finally i've runned supervisor server.coffee and also tried running node-dev server.coffee but it seems the code is wrong when calling the templating engine as you told me but I have no idea what I am doind wrong, that's the point. I need to use the res.render() method though.

Comment: Installing a module doesn't mean it's being used. You must explicitly tell Express what render engine to use before executing `res.render()`. Putting it into `package.json` does nothing for the actually application.

Comment: But in the example I am working they never called the require('eco') and neither the app.register(). They just typed this and it worked. That's my doubt man.

Comment: I have updated my answer one more time. Do make note that you yourself did state that you made notice of the API changes, so what the example you're looking at states really doesn't matter if you ask on here.

Comment: You mean "eco" have also changed the way to render the template?

Comment: Express has changed `app.register()` to `app.engine()`, and Eco support was moved into Consolidate.js.

Comment: Thank's very much. Sorry if I needed to be too specific and I appreciate your time.